# Finding x when slope = 1

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

I've been working out some problems relating to slope on the points of a curve. I'm having issues with this one: In the curve to which the equation is... $$x^2 + y^2 = 4$$

find the value of $x$ at those points where the slope $= 1$. I thought to differentiate and then set $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equal to $1$ and solve for $x$. This seems right but even differentiating this particular equation was confusing to me. As always, many thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: The answers are geometrically obvious, just draw the circle. But it is useful to get control of the approach through derivatives, to handle  cases where the geometry is less clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Applying derivative, $$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac xy$$

$$\implies -\frac xy=1\iff y=-x $$

Put the value of $y$ in the given equation and solve the resulting Quadratic Equation of $x$.

---

Alternatively using coordinate Geometry,  the equation of the tangent will be $y=1\cdot x+c$

Let us find the intersection of the given circle with the starlight line.

Putting the value of $y$ in the given equation

$$(x+c)^2+x^2=4\iff 2x^2+2c x+c^2-4=0$$ which is Quadratic Equation in $x$

For tangency, both the root must be same as the point of intersection must coincide.

So, the discriminant must $(2c)^2-4\cdot2(c^2-4)=0\implies 4c^2=32\implies c=\pm2
\sqrt2$

Consequently, $x=-\frac{2c}2=-c$

Comment: @Blake_B, alternatively, the perpendicular distance of the center $(0,0)$ from the straight line $y-y+c=0$ will be equal to the radius $$\implies \left|\frac{0-0+c}{\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}}\right|=2\implies c=\pm2\sqrt2 $$

Comment: Thank you very much for these detailed answers everyone. They do contain some concepts I am unfamiliar with at the moment but something new to learn and practice is always welcomed here. I haven't quite moved to coordinate geometry yet but I believe there are a few exercises practicing it in the chapter I am currently on.

Answer (score 2):

**A simple Hint:**

When $F(x,y)=0$ defines $y$ as a function of $x$ implicitly, as above, then we have $$y'=\frac{-F_x}{F_y}$$ in which $F_x$ means the partial differential of $F$ with respect to $x$.

- Note that if you want to use this way, you **should** make sure that the relation $F(x,y)=0$ make a functional relation between $y$ and $x$.

Comment: Nice work, as usual!